# Create and draw (un)ordered graphs

Tags: javascript, django, math, graph

Is there any JavaScript app to create and display (un)ordered graphs with possibility to `POST` drawing as JSON array which I can catch and store in Django db?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [d3.js force-directed graph](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/force.html) example. D3 works using javascript to control SVG, so you might be able to serialize the SVG and upload that, rather than an image. If you need an image version of the graph, then you could employ inkscape or some other vector package to render it for you.

An SVG should be more suitable for storage in a DB anyway, particularly if compressed, as it should be smaller for the same image unless the dataset is enormous.

My only query is why you want to task the browser with generating a graph that you then store on the server; if you just want to render images from graphs, there are a number of programs that will do that for you, including the venerable [Graphviz](http://graphviz.org/).

Comment: Graphs will be drawen by users. Thx.